# Regular Expression for 8 or more A's followed by zero, one or two equal signs (=)

Tags: regex

I need to filter out garbage string values, which come in the form of at least 8 A's sometimes followed by ***zero*** (fixed), one or two equal signs.  The examples include the entire string value - if any other characters occur in the string then it's a keeper.

trash:

- AAAAAAAA
- AAAAAAAA=
- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
- AAAAAAAAAAAAA=

keepers:

- AAAAA
- AAAAA=
- AAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
- ==

I'm lame at regular expressions, so request some help.
What expression will permit me to take out the trash?

*Thanks!*

Comment: I assume you mean "0, 1, or 2 equal signs"? Otherwise 2 of your "trash" would hang around.

Comment: `AAAAAAAA0` would be trash or not?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar would NOT be trash

Comment: @KernelPanic You're right - somehow got "zero," omitted from during editing - good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using: `^A{8,}={0,2}$`

---

### Demo (JavaScript):

```js
var regex = /^A{8,}={0,2}$/

console.log([
  // Trash (true)
  'AAAAAAAA',
  'AAAAAAAA=',
  'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
  'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==',
  'AAAAAAAAAAAAA=',
  // Keep (false)
  'AAAAA',
  'AAAAA=',
  'AAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
  '=='
].map(regex.test, regex))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need eight or more `A`s, followed by zero or more equals signs, you can use:

`[A]{8,}[=]{0,}`

Note that this will **also** match the final set of A's in `AAAAA0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`. If you don't want that to match, you should start and end the regex with the delimiters `^` and `$`:

`^[A]{8,}[=]{0,}$`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: OP stipulated 0, 1, or 2 equals signs. Your regex accepts an unbounded number of equals signs (also `{0,}` is just a verbose way of writing `*`.

Answer (score -1):

This regexp may work for you: `^A{8}[A=]` if matched, it's a trash value.